# How to evaluate a NaN equality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, evaluate

How to evaluate this statement in javascript?

```
 isnan = NaN;
 notnan = "hello";
 typeof(notnan) === "number" && isNaN(notnan);
```

Comment: What is expected result? If the first part of the expression is `true` how could the second part of expression also be `true`?

Comment: in right side: two operands are evaluated by and operator then equality checked or equality checked with any operands in the right side then evaluate both results?

Comment: How can the value be a number and not be a number at the same time? As far as am aware of quantum computing is not implemented at JavaScript at this time

Comment: Um whys NaN not working? Its typeof Number but not a number ... :/

Comment: please check this statement:

         typeof(isnan) === NaN               ;      
isnan is nan but results false.

Comment: Because `isNaN` is a function. `NaN` is not a string. `NaN` is not a JavaScript type

Comment: He's trying to see if a string is a number in `typeof(notnan) === "number"`, I believe that is the issue.

Comment: If you are expecting a `true` result for the expression you can use `!` operator `!(typeof(notnan) === "number") /* notnan is not a "number" : false, which we invert to true */ && isNaN(notnan) // again, notnan is not a number,  true && true === true`

Comment: this post solved by another post.

Answer (score 0):

This statment is illogical, because you're trying to see if it's a number and not a number in same statement, making two different booleans output.

```
typeof(notnan) === "number" && isNaN(notnan);
```

I believe you're looking for

```
if (!isNaN(notnan)) {
  // Code if it's a number
} else {
  // Code if it's not a number
}
```

IF you  expect to flip it, you add `!` to start it

```
!isNaN(notnan)
/*
* Returns opposite of isNaN, if it's a number then `true`
* else returns `false`.
*/
```

EDIT:

```
 typeof(notnan) === "number" && isNaN(notnan);
```

Reason this doesn't work is because notnan is a string, therefore it returns false and doesn't evaluate properly. `isNaN` alone works perfectly fine.

Comment: for check a variable (literal) is Nan we must check this variable is typeof number because NaN is number by itself then ckeck this variable is  typeof NaN.

Comment: @hassanmohagheghiyan What's the point of checking such thing if isNaN function itself returns either true or false depending on input. You could use parseInt() to ensure it's a number being processed.

Comment: please check  typeof(isnan) === NaN that results flase!

Comment: `isnan` isn't a function, and NaN equal to itself is false. To properly detect if it's not a number, please use `isNaN()` function.

Answer (score 0):

run this it will say something,

```js
isnan = NaN;
notnan = "hello";
if (typeof(notnan) === "number" && isNaN(notnan)){
  console.log('yes');
}
else {
  console.log('typeof(notnan) is :',typeof(notnan), '\n isNaN(notnan) :', isNaN(notnan),'\n this is,',typeof(notnan)=== "number",'-',isNaN(notnan), 'so this condition became false...')
}
```